# Auth and Priv not working for SNMP v3 traps

Tags: java, snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, snmp-trap

I'm sending v3 traps to my net-snmp container. When I set securityLevel to 1 I get:

```
0.....0...1x....
..........-0+...
..p.....3.8.....
....myuser..s...f'
##..{-..0~.....p
.........Mon Jan
04 18:42:16 CET
20210...+.....me
ssage
```

The security Level 1 is noAuthNoPriv so it works, that's okay. When I set security Level to 2, I log with my username and authPassword, and again it's working! But, when i made a typo in my username I found out that it is working as well :( So instead of valid credentials I could write user: someone password:something and it would still work. And when it comes to security Level 3, whatever I try I can't make it to work. It is always as in the copied result above, however, at the end of the log instead of "message" there is a line of hash code. Does it mean it sees the credentials as wrong ones and that why it is encoded? I can't decode it in any way?
So in summary, with authNoPriv it works everytime, it doesn't care if auth password is correct or not, and with authPriv it never works, it doesn't care if priv password is correct or not. I tried mixing my code with the ones from internet but it didn't help. Here's my code:

```
 TransportMapping transport = new DefaultUdpTransportMapping();
        transport.listen();
        Snmp snmp = new Snmp(transport);

        USM usm = new USM(SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addDefaultProtocols(),
                new OctetString(MPv3.createLocalEngineID()), 0);
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new PrivAES192());
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new PrivAES256());
        SecurityProtocols.getInstance().addPrivacyProtocol(new Priv3DES());
        SecurityModels.getInstance().addSecurityModel(usm);


        String username = "myuser";


        snmp.getUSM().addUser( =
                new OctetString(username),
                new UsmUser(new OctetString(username), AuthMD5.ID, new OctetString(
                        "myAuthPasswd"), PrivAES128.ID, new OctetString("myPrivPasswd")));



        UserTarget target = new UserTarget();
        target.setAddress(new UdpAddress(ipAddress + "/" + port));
        target.setRetries(1);
        target.setTimeout(11500);
        target.setVersion(SnmpConstants.version3);
        target.setSecurityLevel(3);
        target.setSecurityName(new OctetString(username));

        PDU pdu = new ScopedPDU();
        pdu.setType(ScopedPDU.TRAP);
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(SnmpConstants.snmpTrapOID,
                SnmpConstants.linkDown));
        pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID(trapOid), new OctetString("message")));

        snmp.send(pdu, target);
        System.out.println("Sending Trap to (IP:Port)=> " + ipAddress + ":"
                + port);

        snmp.close();
    }
```

Also, here's what I get from container's user table:

```
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserAuthProtocol.".....~"!x..._...."."myuser" = OID: SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmHMACMD5AuthProtocol
```

So this user has MD5 authProtocol.
And

```
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserPrivProtocol.".....~"!x..._...."."myuser" = OID: SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmDESPrivProtocol
```

this user has DES priv protocol. Anyone could help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in adduser try setting to PrivDES.ID instead of PrivAES128.ID,

```
    OID encid = PrivDES.ID;
    if(enc.equalsIgnoreCase("des"))
    {
        encid = PrivDES.ID;
    }
    else if(enc.equalsIgnoreCase("aes")){
        encid = PrivAES128.ID;
    }
    
    
    UsmUser user = new UsmUser(  new OctetString(username),  authid, new 
    OctetString(pass),  encid, new OctetString(pass));
```